# Can zsh chdir search and match history?

Tags: zsh

I'm a newbie of zsh.

Could I type something like `cd %wiki` to jump to `~/prj/golang/gowiki` if it's unique.

But if there are more than two directories posible for `cd %unix`, just show the matching directories.

Here is my sample dirs history.

```
$ dirs -v  
0   ~/prj/golang
1   ~
2   ~/prj/unixconf
3   ~/prj/unixconf/srv
4   ~/memo
5   ~/prj/golang/gowiki
```

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the zshall meta-manpage (`man zshall`) for easiest access to learn about many wonderful zsh tricks. Also notable are the zshcontrib and zshmisc manpages.

Here is an excerpt to help make remembering directories in the dirstack easier.

```
REMEMBERING RECENT DIRECTORIES
   The function cdr allows you to change the working directory to a previous
   working directory from a list maintained automatically.  It is similar in
   concept to the directory stack controlled by the pushd, popd and dirs
   builtins,  but  is  more  config‐ urable,  and  as it stores all entries
   in files it is maintained across sessions and (by default) between
   terminal emulators in the current session.  (The pushd directory stack is
   not actually modified or used by cdr unless you configure it to do so as
   described in the configuration section below.)

Installation
   The system works by means of a hook function that is called every time
   the directory changes.  To install the system, autoload the required
   functions and use the add-zsh-hook function described above:

          autoload -Uz chpwd_recent_dirs cdr add-zsh-hook
          add-zsh-hook chpwd chpwd_recent_dirs

   Now every time you change directly interactively, no matter which command
   you use, the directory to which you change will be remembered in
   most-recent-first order.

Use
All direct user interaction is via the cdr function.

   The argument to cdr is a number N corresponding to the Nth most recently
   changed-to directory.  1 is the immediately preceding directory; the
   current directory is remembered but is not offered as a destination.
   Note that if you have  multiple  windows open 1 may refer to a directory
   changed to in another window; you can avoid this by having per-terminal
   files for storing directory as described for the recent-dirs-file style
   below.

   If you set the recent-dirs-default style described below cdr will behave
   the same as cd if given a non-numeric argument, or more than one
   argument.  The recent directory list is updated just the same however you
   change directory.

   If the argument is omitted, 1 is assumed.  This is similar to pushd's
   behaviour of swapping the two most recent directories on the stack.

   Completion for the argument to cdr is available if compinit has been run;
   menu selection is recommended, using:

          zstyle ':completion:*:*:cdr:*:*' menu selection

   to  allow  you to cycle through recent directories; the order is
   preserved, so the first choice is the most recent directory before the
   current one.  The verbose style is also recommended to ensure the
   directory is shown; this style is on by default so no action is required
   unless you have changed it.
```

For named directories, you will want to use the `hash -d name=/path` and throw it in your zshrc. You can then cd to those directories with `cd ~name`

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can get that without writing a custom version of cd (i.e. creating a function called `cd` that would take over from the `builtin cd`.

You could do something like:

```
DIRSTACKSIZE=20
setopt auto_pushd # Make cd push the old directory onto the directory stack.
setopt pushd_ignore_dups # Ignore duplicates at the directory stack.
setopt pushd_minus # makes the whole pushd list easier to use from 'cd'
```

Then if you did

```
% cd -[TAB]
1 -- /tmp
2 -- /etc
```

You could just use the number:

```
cd -2 # jumps to /etc
```

Also notice that you can use the directory stack from other commands (mv, cp etc) through `~-NUMBER`

```
mv notes.txt ~-[TAB]
1 -- /tmp
2 -- /etc
3 -- /my/very/complicated/dir/path
```